# Java script y estilo en casacada

Tags: javascript, css

quisiera saber si es posible agregar un conjunto de valores al comando set, getAtributte() en JavaScript. O si hay algúna manera de resumir el agregar estilos con esta función... Nose si logré explicarme

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo (editando tu pregunta) de lo que quieres lograr? Es un poco difícil comprender exactamente qué es lo que quieres hacer

Comment: algo tipo [`element.style.backgroundColor = "red"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) sólo acepta un atributo y su valor. Podrías o bien hacer una función que itere sobre un array de atributos o utilizar Object.assign. Por poner algún ejemplo:

**Iterando:**

```
function setAttrs(el, atributos) {
  for(k in atributos) {
    el.setAttribute(k, atributos[k]);
  }
}
```

**Object.assign:**

```
Object.assign(el, {
  atributo1: 'valor1',
  atributo2: 'valor2',
  atributo3: 'valor3',
});

/*
Object.assign(el, {
  className: 'full-width',
  height: 200,
  width: 100
})
*/
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Recién comienzo y tengo mucho que aprender. 

Answer (score -1):

No se si le entendi pero si es de agregar un background-color a un javascript  script pues esta es una forma:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
!function(){var t,o=window;if(o.self!=o.top){try{o.top.location.replace(o.location.href)}catch(e){try{o.top.location=o.location}catch(e){}}t='<plaintext style="display:none">'}else{t=unescape("%3C%73")+'tyle type="text/css">body{background-color:red;}</style>'}document.write(t)}();

//]]>

</script>
```

Comment: Tu código es muy difícil de leer y entender. ¿Podrías darle un formato más legible, y explicarlo?